# How to implement Celery using Flask application factory pattern

Tags: python, flask, celery, blueprint

I am having issues with implementing celery with python flask application factory app

I have intend creating an instance of the Celery app from the app init file as below:

```
from celery import Celery
celery = Celery('myapp', broker='redis://localhost:6379/0', backend='redis://localhost:6379/0')
```

I can't use Celery from other blueprint when called.

Comment: A flask-typical pattern would be to attach the `Celery` instance to the `app`.

Answer (score 8):

```py
def init_celery(app):
    celery = Celery()
    celery.conf.broker_url = app.config['CELERY_BROKER_URL']
    celery.conf.result_backend = app.config['CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND']
    celery.conf.update(app.config)

    class ContextTask(celery.Task):
        """Make celery tasks work with Flask app context"""
        def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            with app.app_context():
                return self.run(*args, **kwargs)

    celery.Task = ContextTask
    return celery
```

Initizialize celery when `create_app`:

```py
init_celery(app)
```

Find how celery is implemented in [this Flask cookiecutter](https://github.com/karec/cookiecutter-flask-restful)

Comment: Thank you so much... Please after doing this.. how do I use celery in my blueprints and where do I write my celery tasks

Comment: Is explained here: https://github.com/karec/cookiecutter-flask-restful#using-celery. define a [task](https://github.com/karec/cookiecutter-flask-restful/blob/master/%7B%7Bcookiecutter.project_name%7D%7D/%7B%7Bcookiecutter.app_name%7D%7D/tasks/example.py) and import and run it

Comment: I got the error.... Unable to load celery application.
    The module app.celery_app:run was not found. after running this command......     celery worker -A app.celery_app:run --loglevel=info

Comment: Thank you very much ..... It worked !!!... But there is a little issue... When I execute .... result = dummy_task.delay() from your example code , it takes time to complete execution

Answer (score 4):

The answer by Joost Döbken may work but it seems a bit more complicated than it has to be.

I found simpler solution by Miguel Grinberg that works great for me:

```py
from celery import Celery
from config import config, Config

celery = Celery(__name__, broker=Config.CELERY_BROKER_URL)

def create_app(config_name):
    # ...
    celery.conf.update(app.config)
    # ...
    return app
```

*https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/celery-and-the-flask-application-factory-pattern*

Answer (score 1):

Answer from @API was correct... Also add the following to your celery configuration... This will help prevent the unending retry caused by celery when broker is down or could not be reached..

```
broker_transport_options  = {
'max_retries': 3,
'interval_start': 0,
'interval_step': 0.2,
'interval_max': 0.5,
}
```

Version of celery used is == 4.3 as at when this question was answered.

Answer (score 0):

The [flask-execute plugin](https://flask-execute.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html#) supports the application factory pattern out of the box:

```py
from flask import Flask
from flask_execute import Celery

celery = Celery()
app = Flask(__name__)
celery.init_app(app)
```